# checking part of a file extension and adding a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check for the following from within the file name:

`images/PRODUCT/icon/`

From the page that contains: `div.lookup-image-wrapper`

If i match them both then i want to add a class to the image that contained:

`images/PRODUCT/icon/`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="lookup-image-wrapper" style="text-align: center">

    <div id="divProductPicZ23280" style="display:none"></div>

    <div class="divProductPic" id="divProductPic23280">
        <img alt="Camping" border="0" id="ProductPic23280" name="ProductPic23280" src="images/Product/medium/23280.jpg">
    </div>

        <img alt="Show Picture 1" border="0" onclick="setcolorpicidx_23280(1);" src="http://i47.tinypic.com/o7szev.jpg" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">

        <img alt="Show Picture 2" border="0" onclick="setcolorpicidx_23280(2);" src="http://i47.tinypic.com/o7szev.jpg" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">

        <img alt="Show Picture 3" border="0" onclick="setcolorpicidx_23280(3);" src="http://i47.tinypic.com/o7szev.jpg" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">

        <img alt="Show Picture 4" border="0" onclick="setcolorpicidx_23280(4);" src="skins/skin_1/images/nopictureicon.gif" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">

        <img alt="Show Picture 5" border="0" onclick="setcolorpicidx_23280(5);" src="images/PRODUCT/icon/23280_5_.jpg" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">
```

**jquery:**

```
$("img[src='images/PRODUCT/icon/']").addClass("selected highlight");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tVvKL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an interesting alternative you could just do this in the CSS as all you're doing is adding a class - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/tVvKL/1/

For example:

```
    img[src*='images/PRODUCT/icon/'] { 
        border: 2px solid red;
    } ​

    img[src^='images/PRODUCT/icon/'] { 
        border: 2px solid red;
    } ​
```

Attribute selectors are supported in IE7+, Firefox 3.0+, Safari 1.3+, Chrome 2+, and Opera 9.2+

http://www.impressivewebs.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Obviously the question is asking in jQuery but the same selector would work in the stylesheet and achieve the same thing.

Comment: Would need to check into that but I just thought it was an interesting point to share. Have updated the answer for you.

Comment: IE7+, Firefox 3.0+, Safari 1.3+, Chrome 2+, and Opera 9.2+

Answer (score 1):

You can use, `wild card *` this will find all images with src containing `images/PRODUCT/icon/`

```
$("div.lookup-image-wrapper > img[src*=images/PRODUCT/icon/]").addClass("selected highlight");
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to check if the page has that other class otherwise the performance of this Jquery on its own will slow the page?

Comment: I have updated my answer for div.lookup-image-wrapper. You can check if you have any performance issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("img[src*='images/PRODUCT/icon/']").addClass("selected highlight");
```

Or

```
$("img[src^='images/PRODUCT/icon/']").addClass("selected highlight");
```

Check the [jQuery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: do i not need an if statement to check the other class, as i just want to do this on the product page.